# Google Cloud Search 3rd Party Connector Media Upload Fail

Tags: c#, google-app-engine

I am attempting to upload a file for indexing using Google.Apis.CloudSearch.v1 in .Net

i am following the instructions provided by google here
https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/reference/rest/v1/media/upload

However i am recieving an error when performing the Upload()

```
{"Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError\r\nCould not decode resource name. [400]\r\nErrors [\r\n\tMessage[Could not decode resource name.] Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]\r\n]\r\n"}
```

for this example, i am using the movie schema 
Please assume that the pdf file is greater then 100 KiB

Code below

```
string resourceName = string.Format("datasources/{0}/items/{1}", config.DS_Id, MovieName);

byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\TEMP\\TEST.pdf");
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

Media m = new Media();
m.ResourceName = resourceName;

UploadItemRef UR = CSService.Indexing.Datasources.Items.Upload(new StartUploadItemRequest() { }, resourceName).Execute();
MediaResource.UploadMediaUpload uploadMediaUpload = new MediaResource.UploadMediaUpload(CSService, m, resourceName, stream, "RAW");
uploadMediaUpload.UploadProtocol = "raw";
uploadMediaUpload.UploadType = "media";
Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress TestUpload = uploadMediaUpload.Upload();
```

Comment: can you please hard code your resourceName with an appropriate value and test it. The error states that are issues with resourceName format.

Comment: i guess this is the problem, there is no detail around what an appropriate value in the resourceName should be. i have tried using a bucket resource, drive, same resource as the item. nothing works. i just need to know what i can enter here for the upload to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer

There is an issue with the .net library.
I found an artical addressing this exact issue on github (Link below)
All credit should go to the auther who first posted this code on github.
As the issue was that the Upload function did not work in the .net library, The solution was to run build the Method manually.
Also, make sure you are using a service account to create the UploadItemRef, if you just use a normal account, it will not error and the upload will not work either. 
This is a copy of the code from github.

```
private void UploadFile(string contentRef, string resourceName, string documentContent)
{
    var uri = $"https://cloudsearch.googleapis.com/upload/v1/media/{contentRef}?uploadType=multipart";

    var token = ((ServiceAccountCredential) _googleClient.HttpClientInitializer).Token.AccessToken;

    using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

    using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent("--BOUNDARY");

    var bodyContent = new StringContent("{ \"resourceName\": \"" + resourceName + "\" }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    content.Add(bodyContent);

    using var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(documentContent));

    using var streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);
    streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");

    content.Add(streamContent);

    // .net adds this header automatically but Google doesn't like it
    foreach (var item in content) item.Headers.Remove("Content-Disposition");

    using var task = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);
    task.Wait(); // don't run async for testing
}
```

more details here

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1481

Comment: Please either add this as a comment on your own Question, or include the important parts of the "more details" here. See ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly your use case, however I would suggest to follow the official documentation. After you added your data source you can perform the search.

> Determine a use case that Google Cloud Search helps to solve.
>
> Identify the repositories holding data relevant to the use case.
>
> Identify the identity systems used by your company to manage access to data in each repository.
>
> Configure access to the Google Cloud Search REST API.
>
> **Add a data source to Google Cloud Search**.

[Introduction to Google Cloud Search](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides)